# Track details about people: Where they live, partner's name, etc

Tags: android, saas

Suppose that to aid their memory, after having a conversation, someone writes down who was spoken to, the things we discussed, etc. then email it to themselves.

Is there any software to manage this content better than gmail? Online or Android preferred, but any names are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

In Android, you can use Contacts to track various things about a person. The under the Notes section of a contact, you can write things like where you met etc. Contacts can then be synced with your laptop or online using any of the various sync software.

If you want something more complex, then you need a CRM system...

But also see description of [Monica - a personal relationship manager](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/52744/app-to-keep-notes-about-people/52747#52747) as this can help you too. It can be self-hosted or run via the webapp service, and then use its Android app to connect to it.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at https://trello.com

I use it for planning, workflows and also to save information about manufacturers/customers. Take a look at the trello example borads: https://trello.com/inspiration